# Cannot run my test with Apache CXF and SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, cxf, java-11

I am experiencing an application problem. I use SpringBoot and Apache CXF to make REST endpoints. It works very well!

However, I encounter a problem when I want to do my unit tests with JUnit.I'm having incompatibility problems between Apache CXF and Springboot.

This only concerns the REST controllers unit test (@RestController), I can test the services without problems.

I tried several ways to correct my problem
- I followed step by step this application https://github.com/jonashackt/soap-spring-boot-cxf
- I watched quite a few similar questions on StackOverflow

CXFConfig

```
@Configuration
public class CXFConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Bus bus;

  @Bean
  public Server rsServer() {
    final JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    endpoint.setBus(bus);
    endpoint.setAddress("/");
    endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(ProductsController()));
    return endpoint.create();
  }

  @Bean
  public ProductsController productController() {
    return new ProductsController();
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    final ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean =
    new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
  }
}
```

The Controller Rest I would like to test:

```
@RestController
public class ProductsController implements Products {

  @Autowired
  ProductService productService;

  @Override
  public PostProductsResponse postProducts(Product entity) {

    //BUISNESS PROCESS NOT SHOW HERE BUT WORKING

    return PostProductsResponse.respond201WithApplicationJson(productImpl);
  }
```

The JUnit test ProductsControllerTest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductsController.class)
@Import(CXFConfig.class)
public class ProductsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    ProductServiceImpl productService;

    private ProductServiceImpl productServiceInit(){
        ProductServiceImpl product = new Product();
        product.setName("Product A");

        return product;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnProductInstantiatedWith201() {
        //Given
        Product product = this.productServiceInit();

        //When
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post("/products")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .content(product.toString())
                )
                .andReturn();

        //Then
        Assert.assertEquals(result.getHeaders(), Products.PostProductsResponse.headersFor201());

    }

}
```

The error I get is bellow. The result I would like is a successful test.

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bus in pacis1.gmop.components.auxiliary.rqp.manager_service.rest.CXFConfig required a bean of type 'org.apache.cxf.Bus' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.apache.cxf.Bus' in your configuration.
```

**SOLUTION 1 PROPOSED BY ... BUT DOESN'T WORK**

```
package ets.components.testcomponent.manager_service.rest;

import org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfAutoConfiguration;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import ets.components.testcomponent.manager_service.config.CXFConfig;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ServiceOrderRestController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CxfAutoConfiguration.class, CXFConfig.class })
public class ProductsControllerTest {


    @Test
    public void testREST() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And the error I get when I run the test 'testREST'

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rsServer' defined in ets.components.testcomponent.manager_service.config.CXFConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rsServer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ets.components.testcomponent.manager_service.rest.ServiceOrderRestController' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ets.components.testcomponent.manager_service.rest.ServiceOrderRestController' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: If someone has any Github projects to show me using the same configuration, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use auto configuration of Spring-Boot in your unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductsController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CxfAutoConfiguration.class, CXFConfig.class })
public class ProductsControllerTest {
...
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution! Also comment your code or explain what you added: annotation `@ContextConfiguration`. There are some JUnit/SpringBoot/Config tutorials you could link to, e.g. [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles).